# How to access the children of a QML Repeater from python?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qml

I built a GUI in QML, then I process the created hierarchy from python, descending down the structure and automatically creating a matching python class hierarchy. I do the recursion by looping over the .children() of a given QML object in the python code. This all works nice, except if I use a Repeater. The repeater object's children() function returns a 2-long list (whereas I have 3 repeated items):

```
[<PyQt5.QtQml.QQmlComponent object at 0x7f0bf5e7bd90>, <PyQt5.QtCore.QObject object at 0x7f0bf5e7bf40>]
```

The .property("count") returns correctly 3, and I can also call .itemAt(0) from within python, like this:

```
print(qmlObject.itemAt(0))
```

but then I get the following error message:

```
TypeError: unable to convert return value of QObject.itemAt from 'QQuickItem*' to a Python object
```

How can this be done? Thank you

Python:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, QUrl, Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine
from PyQt5.QtCore import  pyqtSignal, pyqtSlot
```

QML:

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Window 2.1
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.4
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.1
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.0
import QtQuick.Extras 1.4
```

Comment: Generally speaking, you should try to manage your data via the model not via the delegates. The fact you're trying to access the delegates in this way could indicate that you going about solving a problem the wrong way. Unfortunately, you haven't actually disclosed the actual problem you're trying to solve.